# Bad encoding for PostgreSql Docker instance

Tags: postgresql, docker, encoding, database-connection

I am not able to reach any database located in a running docker container.
I am always having the same error :

```
FATAL: authentification par mot de passe échouée pour l'utilisateur  « ro_user » pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
```

The credentials are correct, and this is below the content of the pg_hba.conf :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
host all all all md5
```

Same PostgreSQL images are working for my coworkers, is there any configuration I need to add to be allowed to connect to the database ? Is this related to my ip address or to the OS encoding ?

Comment: Your database is only listening on localhost (::1 / 127.0.0.1), so it is impossible to connect from outside to the database server in your docker container. The warning is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: I change the value for 0.0.0.0/0 and I still have the same error. What should I set up ?

Comment: I solved this by using another "outside" port than `5432` on my docker container. For example `5433`. So my docker port mapping became `5433:5432`.
Not sure why the default outside port `5432` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

just check in your task manager if there's any postgres server running
==>terminated  (end task)
also check if you have anything running on port 5432 ==> (you have to change it to run on a different port)

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck with the same problem as you.

For me the issue was that I had PostgreSQL installed locally on my machine and it was interferring with the Docker PostgreSQL I had up.

The solution is simple and you have 2 options like other guys pointed out.

- Uninstall local PostgreSQL from your machine.
- Change the destination port from the container (For example, change it for the 5433).

Answer (score -1):

It could be you have antoher local database installed, delete the local database i had works for me

Comment: That is a very drastic suggestion